# jQuery autocomplete functionality - not sure how to get current text in field

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I currently have something like this in my autocomplete jQuery code:

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: "/problems/get_categories_ajax.php?category="+$(this).data("autocomplete", ui.item.autocomplete),
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#user_id").val(ui.item.id);
            $(this).data("user_id",ui.item.id);//Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element
            $(this).data("username",ui.item.value);//Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element

    },
        selectFirst: true,
        autoFill: true,
        mustMatch: true
})
.bind("blur",function() {
    var autocomplete = $(this).data("autocomplete");

    $(this).val(autocomplete);
    $("#autocomplete").val(autocomplete);
});
```

but I get the error that I can't use the ui variable when trying to construct the AJAX call here: source: "/problems/get_categories_ajax.php?category="+$(this).data("autocomplete", ui.item.autocomplete),

How can I get the value from the form to pass in there?

Thanks!

Comment: `$(this).data("autocomplete", ui.item.autocomplete)` sets the data=autocomplete value, it does not retrieve it

Comment: I see. I am just working from an example which I don't fully understand.  Was hoping for some guidance here of how to set this sort of thing up to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add it manually as a parameter. It would be automatically appended as `term`.

If you need to specify a different parameter name, then you should declare a custom `source` function:

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        q: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response( data );
      }
    });
  }
});
```

(Source: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)